# Debian: can't send email with SSMTP as regular user

Tags: debian, ssmtp

I'm having some trouble getting SSMTP to let me send email as a regular user. When I set up this machine ~a year ago, I'd used [Arch's instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) to set up security, but that apparently broke silently at some point with (I assume) an update, and I just realized that I haven't been getting email from cron and whatnot. I'd rather not have to hope that I notice when ssmtp updates and go change everything manually.

I'm getting what looks like a classic permission error:

```
$ echo "This is a test" | mail -s "Subject" <my email>
send-mail: Cannot open mailhub:25
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

This works perfectly fine when I run mail with sudo. However, my permissions look fine:

```
$ sudo ls -l /usr/sbin/ssmtp 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39784 Jul 14  2014 /usr/sbin/ssmtp
$ sudo ls -l /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root root 699 Dec 28 16:35 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

I've added my user to the "root" group, which seems little iffy, although I'd tried using the "mail" group earlier:

```
$ groups
root mail [...]
```

The frustrating part is that I've got a ubuntu box sitting here with what looks like exactly the same configuration, except that it works. What the heck am I doing wrong? [This machine is running Debian "stretch", ssmtp package version 2.64-8+b2]

Edit- As requested, I tried using mail in verbose mode, which didn't yield any additional output (?)

```
$ echo "Test" | mail -v -s "Test" my@email.com
send-mail: Cannot open mailhub:25
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

Comment: a `strace` might indicate what `send-mail` is doing right before issuing that error

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how to use strace :/ I have no significant programming (or debugging) experience.

Comment: Please add debugging output by pasting the output of: `echo test|mail -v -s "test" your@mail.com`

Answer (score 2):

If you used those [Arch configuration instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP) the part you're missing after a Debian upgrade is that there is nothing to tell Debian to reapply the setgid bit. Run these two commands (or use the script `/root/bin/ssmtp-set-permissions` if you created that)

```
chown :ssmtp /usr/bin/ssmtp
chmod g+s /usr/bin/ssmtp
```